# How to dynamically change the SVG object color using a JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, svg

I constructed a network with about 1000 nodes in SVG format. Now I want to change the color of all the nodes dynamically (with time). For starters I just want to make sure that the circles/nodes in my SVG figure change colors with time based on a random number generator. Can I use a simple for loop in JavaScript to bring about N number of node color changing events?

This is the function I wrote hoping that it would change the color of a particular node/circle hundred times triggered by single mouse click

```
function ChangeRandomNodeColor(){
  var mycircle = document.getElementById("node_1150")   
  for (i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    var r = Math.random()
    if (r < 0.33) {
      mycircle.style.fill = "yellow" ;
    } 
    else if (r < 0.66) {
      mycircle.style.fill = "cyan" ;
    } 
    else {
      mycircle.style.fill = "black" ;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately all it does is to change the color only once per every mouse click, it's as though the for loop is completely useless!

Comment: Write some code and post it with the question.

Comment: I just added. Please take a look at it. Thank You

Comment: This is on hold, but you need to set a timeout on that function, or an interval. The `for` loop changes the colour 100 times, but you can only see one. So you'd have to give it an interval.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consdider following rect as one node . Use window.setInterval function for timer  and use Math.Random fucntion to generate a random number and use according your requirement.

```
  <svg>
      <rect width="100px" height="100px" fill="yellow" id="one">
      </rect>
  <svg>

document.getElementById("one").style.fill = "red";
```